# How to increase click radius in bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

I'm doing some simple plotting and would like to increase the usability of my figure.

I have quite a lot of points on my graph and have issues with selecting the ones I want because the click radius is so tiny.

I can increase the circle radius of my point but the radius of the area which displays a tooltip is still only 1 dot. Can I increase the radius somehow without having to create additional points around which respond the same?

Would it be even possible to increase the click detection radius without increasing the actual circle radius?

Answer (score 2):

in the current version (0.8.2) and in the upcoming version (0.9) this is not yet a tunable parameter. It would be a good feature to expose a click radius, so I have made an issue on our issue tracker, that you can follow, here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2230

In the short term, a possible workaround is to have a second, invisible set of glyphs that are used for hit testing. They would be at the same locations, but bigger, to provide a bigger hit area.